# Run program with an expiration time/duration

Tags: go, duration

I've been searching on the internet but I did not find the right answer, so, my question is, how can I run a Go program during 5 minutes and after this 5 minutes exit the script?

Comment: You’re looking for a Go equivalent of sleep()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this line of code to the beginning of the `main()` function:

```
time.AfterFunc(5*time.Minute, func() { os.Exit(0) })
```

This causes `os.Exit(0)` to be called after 5 minutes.

Here it is on the Go playground (minutes convert to seconds for example): https://play.golang.org/p/wybKWM2BEep

Comment: Your example could show that the exit is taken: https://play.golang.org/p/it1kmQViavN